# Creating two rows with wookmark

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wookmark

I am trying to implement the wookmark js in my design for a pinterest like layout. But instead of the usual single instance of wookmark in a page, I need it to be applied twice on the page. But I am having an issue. When the first row gets arranged, it is pushing the second row too much down with an empty space in between them.

[image: You can see the blank white space between the red and blue rows.]

You can see the blank white space between the red and blue rows. I want the blue row to start immediately below the red one.

Here is my fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/u3ndne03/1/

**HTML**

```
<div class="wookmark">
    <div class="singleitem red">s</div>
    <div class="singleitem red">s</div>
    <div class="singleitem red">s</div>
    <div class="singleitem red">s</div>
    <div class="singleitem red">s</div>
</div>        

<div class="wookmark">
    <div class="singleitem blue">s</div>
    <div class="singleitem blue">s</div>
    <div class="singleitem blue">s</div>
    <div class="singleitem blue">s</div>
    <div class="singleitem blue">s</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wookmark {
    position: relative; /** Needed to ensure items are laid out relative to this container **/
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0; 
}
.singleitem{
    border:1px solid #000;
    background:red;
    width:60px;
    height:60px
}
.red {
    background:red;
}
.blue {
    background:blue;
}
```

**JS**

```
$('.wookmark .singleitem').wookmark({
    autoResize: true, // This will auto-update the layout when the browser window is resized.
    container: $('.wookmark'), // Optional, used for some extra CSS styling
    offset: 5, // Optional, the distance between grid items
    itemWidth: 60, // Optional, the width of a grid item
});
```

Any idea friends?

Comment: Like [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/o44773sz/)?

Comment: @JoshCrozier : but its not working when I have some normal text in between the rows. Please see http://jsfiddle.net/ynzqo542/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that each instance is sharing a common container element. It doesn't appear that wookmark was design to handle cases like this. Without changing the HTML, one possible solution would be to loop through the `.wookmark` elements and capture the context of its parent element and pass that as the container element like this:

[**Updated Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/fc3q2pzo/)

```
$('.wookmark').each(function () {
    var parent = $(this).closest('.wookmark');
    $(this).find('.singleitem').wookmark({
        autoResize: true,
        container: parent,
        offset: 5,
        itemWidth: 60,
    });
});
```